# Is there a way of multiplying a polynomial in X &Y with fractional powers with another such polynomial to get polynomial in X &Y with integer powers?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-fields

I want to take something like $X^{m/k}+X^{(m-1)/k}+Y^{1/k}$ and multiply it by another polynomial in $X^{1/k}$ and $Y^{1/k}$ to get a polynomial without fractional powers, ideally irreducible in $K[x,y]$, $K$ a finite field. Is that possible in general? Is there a general procedure to find such a polynomial?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your element is surely algebraic over the field $K(X,Y)$ and integral over $K[X,Y]$. This answers the question in the affirmative. The constant term of its minimal polynomial over $K(X,Y)$ is a product of its conjugates (possibly raised to $p$th power a few times, if $p\mid k$, should the minimal polynomial be inseparable). That constant term is then also an element of $K[X,Y]$. The conjugates have the same terms with various $k$th roots of unity as coefficients,

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! I think I'm seeing at least part of the answer to my question: use the finite module basis for $K[X^{1/3},Y^{1/3}]$ over $K[X,Y]$ to consider multiplication by $X^{2/3}+X^{1/3}+Y^{1/3}$ as a linear transformation with associated matrix A with entries in $K[X,Y]$ and use Cayley-Hamilton on $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: Yes! That should work. Feel free to flesh it out to a full answer. That way you get feedback on the details, and we can mark this thread solved :-)